# Max. number of parallel background threads (backend)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How many parallel background threads can I start in one google app engine backend? I didn't find any information to the amount of parallel allowed threads. I'm using Java for the GAE.

I start a new thread as explained in the docs: [1]

```
return ThreadManager.createBackgroundThread(new Runnable() { ... });
```

If I run my application, after a while the following exception is thrown (at the creation of a new thread):

```
com.google.appengine.api.system.SystemFailureException: An unknown error occurred
```

This [2] issue mentioned that this exception appears if the API is out of quota. So i can create threads, but after a certain time the exception appears. That's why i think there is a limit of threads in a backend.

[1] https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview#background_threads

[2] http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7398

Comment: When do you start to see this issue? E.g. does it happen when you create a certain number of threads? The default backend instance type only comes [with 128M of memory](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview#Billing_Quotas_and_Limits). Depending on the memory footprint of each thread, you may also run out of memory. In a Python GAE app you could actually [measure the memory usage of your backend instance through the Runtime API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/runtimeapi).

Comment: I edited my question. Yeah, I can create threads in a backend without problems. I'm using the B4 backend with 512M of memory, so i don't think that I'm falling out of memory. But you're right, this happens when I created a certain number of threads (but i don't know how many).

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue to determine how many threads are running when this happens?

Comment: I cant say how much threads are allowed, but i know that the GAE has a thread limit. I use a task queue to call my backend and do some work. After a while some of the tasks failed, but the backend didn't throw an error. So I think if the thread limit is reached, you can't create new background processes or neither start new tasks on the backend. Because of that, I can't say how much threads are allowed :( . I will create an answer and show how I, more or less, bypassed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was the API limit of the backends. I could start as many threads as I want, but when I reached the API limit (100 simultanous calls) the creation of new threads was not possible. Quotas and limits are described in [their docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview#Billing_Quotas_and_Limits).

I reduced my API calls (database, google cloud storage) to speed up the performance of the application and the exception is gone :) .

Answer (score 6):

For the record, App Engine distinguishes between [normal threads](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/?hl=en#sandboxing_in_python), which can't outlive the HTTP request that started them, and [background threads](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/#Python_Background_threads), which can.

**For Python**, at least, it looks like the production (Python 2.7) runtime and dev_appserver both impose a **fixed limit of 10 background threads per backend**, independent of 
other settings like e.g. `max_concurrent_requests` in
[backends.yaml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/backends?hl=en#Go_Backends_definitions).

I've talked with a few other old App Engine team members, and while they weren't
100% sure, they said this sounded right. I've confirmed empirically with the
test backend config and code below. I also tried starting more background threads from a separate HTTP request, and from yet another background thread. No luck; same overall limit of 10 total.

Here's where the SDK sets that limit in dev_appserver (specifically devappserver2 in SDK 1.8.8) for Python:
[instance.py:449](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/instance.py?r=404#449),
[python_runtime.py:61](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python_runtime.py?r=404#61).
It looks like background threads are disabled altogether for Go and Java:
[go_runtime.py:99](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/go_runtime.py?r=404#99),
[java_runtime.py:61](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/java_runtime.py?r=404#61).

One interesting quirk: inside a background thread, it looks like you can start as many normal threads as you want, at least until you hit the memory limit. They don't hold any HTTP request open, and they don't seem to get cut off by a deadline either. I'm currently doing this to work around the background thread limit.

I wish this was documented! Would have saved me a lot of time.

---

**backends.yaml**

```
- name: test
  instances: 1
  start: threadtest.application
```

**test.py**

```
def test():
  for i in range(100):
    logging.info('Starting #%d', i)
    background_thread.start_new_background_thread(time.sleep, [20])

class Start(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    background_thread.start_new_background_thread(test, [])

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/_ah/start', Start)], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the exception, I'll assume you're using Java.

How are you creating the threads? You should use ThreadManager (as opposed to calling "new Thread()", which is not supported).

By *background thread* do you mean code in a backend? You need to start background threads in a backend task.

For the record, each request is limited to 50 threads.

Read up on threads [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime?hl=en#Requests_and_Servlets).